# Managing Urls in WebForms

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a large Webforms application.  In many places throughout the application we set the navigation urls of hyperlinks in code behind.  Hard coding string literals seems like a bad idea.

```
hlVideos.NavigateUrl = "/path/to/some/page.aspx";
```

This doesn't seem like a good idea either, since it could require me to have a constant string on every page that needs it:

```
private const string PathToSomePage = "/path/to/some/page.aspx";

hlVideos.NavigateUrl = PathToSomePage;
```

I've thought about a single class with a bunch of const strings in it that can be accessed.  This seems like it would be an open/closed principle violation, requiring me to add another constant every time that I add a new page.

```
public class UrlManager
{
    public const string PathToSomePage = "/path/to/some/page.aspx";
    public const string PathToSomeOtherPage = "/path/to/some/other/page.aspx";
    public const string PathToYetAnotherPage = "/path/to/yet/another/page.aspx";
}
```

How is everyone else handling this?  Maybe I'm over complicating this, although I am dealing with a hundred urls or so with many pages referencing each url.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a resource file.  That way you can maintain a consistent reference to pages, but it is easily maintainable in code and easily hot-fixed post-deployment if the situation requires.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to write some T4 template to generate your UrlManager file class. Something like T4MVC. Look here for WebForms example [T4Mvc web forms](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidebb/archive/2009/07/12/asppathguru-a-little-t4-love-for-asp-net-webforms.aspx)